# Xcode App missing Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

In my Xcode App there is no Cocoa Touch. How do I fix that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the iPhone SDK from http://developer.apple.com. Support for iPhone development does not come with the regular Xcode which is distributed with Leopard.